# K means clustering of variable with multiple values

Tags: r, clustering, mean, k-means

I have a sample data below that is from a large data set, where each participant is given multiple condition for scoring.

```
 Participant<-c("p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p3")
 Condition<-c( "c1","c2","c1","c2","c1","c2")
 Score<-c(4,5, 5,7,8,2)
 T<-data.frame(Participant, Condition, Score)
```

I am trying to use K-mean clustering to split participants in different groups, is there any good way to do it, considering the condition is not numeric?

thanks!

Comment: If you only have two conditions, you can turn Condition into a binary variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I apologize, I didn't read your previous post in StackOveflow too closely. Now that I have, here's how I'd do this. Note that I'm a) changing Condition to be a factor and b)re-casting this dataframe to show what you're hoping to show.

```
Participant<-c("p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p3")
Condition<-c( "c1","c2","c1","c2","c1","c2")
Score<-c(4,5, 5,7,8,2)
#NOTE THAT CONDITION IS NOW A FACTOR
T<-data.frame(Participant, Condition = factor(Condition), Score)
library(reshape2)
T = dcast(T, Participant ~ Condition)
row.names(T) = T$Participant
T = T[,-1]
print(T)
#    c1 c2
# p1  4  5
# p2  5  7
# p3  8  2
kmeans(T,2)
# K-means clustering with 2 clusters of sizes 2, 1
# 
# Cluster means:
#    c1 c2
# 1 4.5  6
# 2 8.0  2
# 
# Clustering vector:
# p1 p2 p3 
#  1  1  2 
# 
# Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
# [1] 2.5 0.0
#  (between_SS / total_SS =  88.3 %)
#
```

Presumably your real dataset has more than 3 points, but this method should generalize well.

Comment: Thank you very much jarfa. This approach makes perfect sense. There is something extra that I missed in my original question. If Each participant has multiple scores for each condition. then I should calculate the mean score per condition and apply the method you provided, is this correct?

Comment: What's important is that each participant has only one row. The mean for each condition seems like a reasonable way of doing this.